# Minimizing QUAD count of a 3D mesh

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, polygon, mesh

Given a disorderly array of miniature quad polygons on a 2D plane, What are some of the best ways of grouping them into larger quads?

Currently i am writing the quads into a boolean array so that i can fast access all neighbor values of a given quad, and construct logical grouped squares and rectangles containing many neighbor squares.

```
var BoolGrid: new Boolean[100x100];

function CheckNeighbor (x, y){return BoolGrid(x + y*100 );}
```

Do you have a logical process to group quads? Reverse Octree? Spiral around starting point? flexible conditions to find multiple optimal large squares that contain a starting square?

It's quite a fun and challenging computing challenge similar to rubix, please share any thoughts on the topic. Here's an example where it's been done wrong:
[image]
ill add another pic while it's on the pc: free program from thingiverse optimized quads. only other program i know does this is 3dsmax at 1000USD!
[image]

Comment: quad trees are inefficient for grouping rectangles, a rectangle of 100 units contains 100 quad tree squares versus only 1 quad using a different process.

Comment: using staircase surfaces, trying to do complex squares probably results in as many quads as simply doing quads of n length and one  unit high, which is a lot easier and can be simplified further. A pre-test to determine if the plane will contain more long or high type quads is convenient, else do both long and high quad filling in alternate runs and keep the smallest.

Comment: hmm the "QUADs" (triangles really) in your images are overlapping that is not a valid result in most mesh related applications and algorithms. Your tags and title where wrong hence no answers after 1.5 years ...

Comment: it's all right i solved this. I was writing a program algorythm. The downloaded program from the photo was indeed faulty, that is why I had to write a new program.